# SharePoint 2013 Patching - Which is the stable CU post July 2016 CU?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching

We are patching our SharePoint 2013 Servers after a very long time. Since July 2016, the servers are not patched. Initially we thought its good to keep 6 months of lag from the current patching, which took us to Nov 2017 CU. But from the blog [Nov 2017 CU Bug](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4c25912-7ba5-4401-bcde-9dfffad0346d/bug-with-cu-november-2017-for-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral)  literally scared us from going forward. Is there latest stable SP CU post July 2016?

Answer (score 1):

We recommend you to use the latest CU for SharePoint 2013. It can fix the relevant issue which included in previous versions of CU.

[SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers and CU’s](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steve_chen/sharepoint-2013-build-numbers-and-cus/)

Answer (score 1):

I have lately installed [May 2018 CU for SharePoint 2013](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/sp2013may2018.aspx) on several customer-farms without any issues. It was released on may 8th, so it had some time to age. June 2018 CU was released about two weeks ago. **I** wouldn't install it after such a short period of being public. But i also do not see any reason to stay six months behind.

One very good source for CUs is maintained by ToddKlindt in his [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) post. Especially look at the "Bugs, Notes and regressions" where he collects all reported drawbacks on a CU.

BTW: The November 2017 CU was not buggy itself. It seems that some customers [didn't apply their patches as they should](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2017/12/05/after-updating-sharepoint-2013-to-november-2017-cu-or-later-you-may-not-be-able-to-open-documents-with-office/). So there is no resolution in any following CU for that problem.

Comment: i have seen the resolution, but is the standard way to run config wizard after every patch or is applicable only nov CU ?

Comment: Standard-Behavoir. See my answer on your other question for all the weird details that work in real-life. ;-)